# Ubuntu 19.10 CPU usage 100%

Tags: cpu, 19.10

[Updated with extra info as requested in comments]

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 19.10 (via 19.04) and have noticed my fan going nuts ever since.  Looking at System Monitor I can see all 4 cores are going crazy but there's nothing significant in the Process list when  filtered from high to low.

Anybody any ideas? This is an i7 laptop with AMD Radeon graphics and 8 GB RAM.

[image: Monitor Resources]

[image: Monitor Processes]

[image: Top output]

Comment: Can you post the Process List too?

Comment: Indeed include the output of the command `top` in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the screen shots (Process and Resources from Monitor and a screenshot of Top)

Comment: Seeing the huge java proces, you do not happen to run minecraft? https://askubuntu.com/questions/896937/high-cpu-usage-with-minecraft-systemd-service

Comment: No, see reply below. Docker containers were the culprit

Comment: Did you manually configure the drivers for your graphics card on 19.10?

Comment: @OmariCelestine No, it was a straight-forward upgrade (18.04 -> 19.04 -> 19.10) and I don't remember having tweaked graphics drivers originally.

Comment: So you never had to install the amdgpu drivers?

Comment: @OmariCelestine not that I recall no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies all but I have figured it out.  I saw docker in Top output and checked what containers I had running (2 databases, a Wordpress and a Spring Boot app I had written).  Stopping these containers has stopped the fan thrashing and brought CPU usage right down.
So slightly embarrassing but a big relief. Thanks.

Comment: In two days click the grey check mark next to your answer so others know the accepted answer to solving the problem. Thanks.